# Display 6 months before date selected PHP

Tags: php, datepicker

I have a problem for get 6 months before the date selected. This is my code

```
$tgl_akhir = $_POST['datepicker'];
$tgls = strtotime($tgl_akhir," -6 month");
$tgl_awal = date("d-M-Y",$tgls);

<?php echo $tgl_akhir." - ".$tgl_awal ?>
```

and this is the result

[image]

Comment: Well, you substract  6 months on the first date and make a second date from the previous one... There's no problem about it ! Just substract 6 months on the second one !

Comment: Can you show that links ? @S.Bureau

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma in the strtotime. You need to make it a string with a dot and strtotime will read it as `"date" - 6 months` as you expect.

```
$tgl_akhir = "01-Oct-2018";
$tgls = strtotime($tgl_akhir. " -6 month");
$tgl_awal = date("d-M-Y",$tgls);

echo $tgl_akhir." - ".$tgl_awal;
//01-Oct-2018 - 01-Apr-2018
```

https://3v4l.org/jq7SV

Comment: Thank you very much @andreas, It helps me

Comment: @FranksyeSipangkar no problem!

Comment: @FranksyeSipangkar feel free to accept the answer if it's what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `DateTime` object you can do it like this:

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$modified = $date->modify("-6 months");
```